# Using sql SELECT DISTINCT in Fusion Tables API

Tags: javascript, sql, google-fusion-tables

How do I go about using sql SELECT DISTINCT in fusion tables API?

Comment: It does not seem to be supported (Officially) https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference

Comment: Am getting this recurrence in the column my column table as seen in the image below. I only want three options; Urban, rural and peri urban. How do i go about doing that?

http://postimg.org/image/50jz3oi9n/

Comment: muito obrigado me ajudou muito [Thank you very much, it helped me a lot.] converted answer to comment with translation.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't use SELECT DISTINCT, you can use a GROUP BY to solve some of the same problems as DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, address from TABLEID
```

and

```
SELECT name, address from TABLEID group by name, address
```

should yield the same results. Fusion Tables SQL is quirky though so you may need to throw a "count()" into your SELECT statement.

(Yes, old thread.)